# How can I choose values from stacked raster images according to location of ROI

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, erdas-imagine, envi

Before I choosed ROI on land surface temperature (LST) images and obtained pixel values of LST. Now I need pixel value of another images which are stacked multi-band image. My main purpose is to obtain pixel values of both images "at the same location". I think that I can use ROI file from LST to choose the pixel values of multiband image. Anyone who guide me to accomplish this purpose using ARCGIS, ENVI, ERDAS?

I choosed the ROI in rectangular mood in ENVI. When I opened it, it looks like small polygons (not points) spreading on my study area.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to export the ENVI ROIs as a shp file. You can then load the shp in ArcGIS together with the stacked multiband image. Then use either the "sample" or "extract multi values to points" tools to sample the raster image at the specific points of your shape files.