# Spectral profile (z-profile) viewer for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, remote-sensing, multi-band, viewer

I have multilayer raster with 6 bands. Is there a way to select one specific pixel and to display the z profile (the values of each band) for this pixel as a chart or table? I am looking for a tool similar to the spectral profile viewer of ENVI: [link](http://www.ltid.inpe.br/tutorial/images/tut14_13.gif)

As a workaround I tried to cast my raster pixels into points but there are way too many of them for a smooth display.

Comment: Do you want to *output* a table, or just *view* one? Using the Identify tool (blue circle with a white 'i' in it, same toolbar as zoom controls) and clicking on a pixel should open a window that has a list of each band and the value at that location on that band. If you want a bunch of values, this may be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81958/how-can-i-choose-values-from-stacked-raster-images-according-to-location-of-roi

Comment: Yes I know the identifier tool and it is good for a first impression of the data, but my final result should be a pop-up displaying a chart with the band numbers on its x-axis and the value of the band on its y-axis. It should look like this: [link](http://www.ltid.inpe.br/tutorial/images/tut14_13.gif) I thought of doing this with a html pop up but this tool only works on feature data and I can not cast my raster pixel to points because there would be too many of them (10^8 points).

Answer (score 1):

Use Extract Values to Points in Spatial Analyst Extension. Also you can use Extract Multi Values to Points. You need a shapefile with the points of interest. This tool add the values of the raster to the attribute table of the  shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Identifier tool can be used as a simple solution, but, true, no chart, and it will only show the brightness values for the 3 bands that happen to be loaded in the 3 channels (RGB).

One solution that might suit you better is to download the free MultiSpec program https://engineering.purdue.edu/~biehl/MultiSpec/.

Once installed, just bring in your image file, then under "Window" access the "New Selection Graph" function.

Then, zoom in on a pixel of interest, and simply click (once or twice, till you get a cross-cursor) and you will get a chart showing the BVs for ALL the bands associated with that pixel, not just 3 bands.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be in ArcGIS or could it be another package?

If you don't mind using another package there is a free viewer called TuiView (https://bitbucket.org/chchrsc/tuiview/) which will display z-profiles very similar to ENVI you might want to look at. For ENVI files it will read the wavelengths from the header and use these.

There are some more details, with an example of the plots in this post: https://spectraldifferences.wordpress.com/2015/02/15/viewing-hyperspectral-data-in-tuiview/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such tool in ArcGIS (unlike GRASS and ENVI, for instance). The best tool in your case would be the "pixel inspector"  ([customize > command > raster](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Adding_the_Pixel_Inspector_tool_to_a_toolbar/009t00000098000000/)), where you can see the value of the 3 bands that are rendered interactively in a matrix (there is no graph, though). Like the identify tool, only the rendered bands are visible (only three bands).

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the [training sample evaluation window](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Training_sample_evaluation_tools/00nv00000007000000/) (in the classification toolbar) to get an idea of the values of a multiple band raster. This is still not exactly what you want, but at least you can visualize all bands at once.